# What do my first difference ACF/PACF show me?

Tags: arima, autocorrelation, acf-pacf

I am quite new to econometrics, so not sure how to intepret the following acf/pacf function on log financial time series after first differencing;

[image]

The level data showed a AR(1) process, how would I interpret this one?

thank you

Comment: If my answer was helpful .. please accept it to close the question

Answer (score 0):

if there are no pulses , level/step shifts , seasonal pulses ,local time trends ....white noise is my suggestion

Comment: So this would be a White noise process, ie. serially uncorrelated? are there any implications for financial time series of a white noise process.   thank you!

Comment: The best forecast for the next period is the last observation .....thus a random walk